# How to configure systemd to start a service when a particular file not exist and stop when exist

Tags: systemd

Is it poosible to start a systemd service (A.service) if a file (F) NOT exists and stop it when F appears?
Unfortunately the .path Unit only supports 'PathExists=F' and there is no 'PathExists=!F'.

Answer (score 0):

Create another .service unit that either

- runs `systemctl --no-block stop <main>.service`,
- or runs `/bin/true` but has `Conflicts=<main>.service`.